# dash-leaflet (geojson): change color of last clicked feature

Tags: python, leaflet, geojson, plotly-dash

I'm trying to change color of polyline (feature) on click, but I don't know how. I know there is component click_feature and I should use it somehow (so I can target specific feature, but I don't know how to update color).

Something like that:

```
app.clientside_callback(
    """function(feature){
        // set and return color
        ;}""",
    Output("geojson", ???), # To what children?
    Input("geojson", "click_feature")
    )
```

So any ideas, how to change color of specific feature on click event?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your are working with the `GeoJSON` component, you must encode all information on how features should be drawn in the *rendering* function, i.e. the `style` prop (polygons) and the `point_to_layer` prop. To color a particular polygon grey for example, the structure would be something like

```
function(feature, context){
        const match = ...
        if(match) return {weight:5, color:'#666', dashArray:''};
};
```

where `match` is the condition that determines which polygon(s) to color grey. To achieve interactivity, you can use the `hideout` prop. You could e.g. set it to the last clicked feature,

```
app.clientside_callback("function(feature){return feature}", Output("states", "hideout"), [Input("states", "click_feature")])
```

Combining these two concepts, it is possible to highlight a feature on click. Here is a small example using the [us-states dataset](https://dash-leaflet.herokuapp.com/assets/us-states.pbf),

```
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_leaflet as dl
from dash import Dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
from dash_extensions.javascript import assign

# Color the feature saved in the hideout prop in a particular way (grey).
style_handle = assign("""function(feature, context){
    const match = context.props.hideout &&  context.props.hideout.properties.name === feature.properties.name;
    if(match) return {weight:5, color:'#666', dashArray:''};
}""")
# Create example app.
app = Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([
    dl.Map(center=[39, -98], zoom=4, children=[
        dl.TileLayer(),
        dl.GeoJSON(url="/assets/us-states.pbf", format="geobuf", id="states", 
                   options=dict(style=style_handle), hideout=dict(click_feature=None))
    ], style={'width': '100%', 'height': '50vh', 'margin': "auto", "display": "block"}, id="map"),
])
# Update the feature saved on the hideout prop on click.
app.clientside_callback("function(feature){return feature}", Output("states", "hideout"), [Input("states", "click_feature")])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: It works, great! I though I should do something like that. Now I understand the hideout component very well! Thank you for your work and awesome dash-leaflet! Looking forward to new updates and features.

Comment: I have one more question, right know the hover implementation is that, what feature you hover last on, it will have the highest z-index. But I want to have the clicked feature to be with the highest z-index, so the feature ​will not be under the other features. I tried to do it with adding className and via CSS z-index property. But it doesn't work.

Comment: I would suggest creating a separate GeoJSON component for the clicked feature. Wrapping this "clicked-feature-geojson" component in a Pane component, you can control the z-index via CSS.